# Better option than pandas iterrows

Tags: python, pandas

I have following table in pandas. the table contains time and the price of the product.

For analysis purposes, I want to have 2 columns which would contain the next time when the product is more than $100 price change in either direction.

e.g. if I am at cell 09:19 cell the next price more than $100 higher would be 14:02 & less than $100 lower would be 11:39 so 14:02 & 11:39 should come in 09:19 row in respective columns.

Same way against cell 09:56, next price more than $100 higher would be 14:02 & less than $100 lower would be 12:18 so these 2 values would come in against the row of 09:56.

```
Table
Time        Price    Up_Time   Down_Time
09:19:00    3252.25     
09:24:00    3259.9      
09:56:00    3199.4      
10:17:00    3222.5      
10:43:00    3191.25     
11:39:00    3143        
12:18:00    2991.7      
13:20:00    3196.35     
13:26:00    3176.1      
13:34:00    3198.85     
13:37:00    3260.75     
14:00:00    3160.85     
14:02:00    3450        
14:19:00    3060.5      
14:30:00    2968.7      
14:31:00    2895.8      
14:52:00    2880.7      
14:53:00    2901.55     
14:55:00    2885.55     
14:57:00    2839.05     
14:58:00    2871.5      
15:00:00    2718.95
```

I am using following code, which works but takes 15-20 mins for 1 dataset.

```
for i, row in df.iterrows():
    time_up = np.nan
    time_down = np.nan

    for j in range(i+1, len(df)):
        diff = df.iloc[j]['Price'] - row['Price']
        if diff > 100:
            time_up = df.iloc[j]['Time']
        elif diff < -100:
            time_down = df.iloc[j]['Time']

        if not pd.isna(time_up) or not pd.isna(time_down):
            break

    df.at[i, 'Up_Time'] = time_up
    df.at[i, 'Down_Time'] = time_down
```

Is there any more efficient way to do it?

Comment: When you say `less than $100` do you actually mean `more negative than -$100`?

Comment: Yes. Means if its -101 then that time should come in down_time col

Comment: diff should be more than 100 or less than -100

Answer (score 2):

You do need to compare each row's `Price` value with all the rows that come after it, so some amount of iteration is necessary. You can do that with `apply` and a function using numpy to find the first value which meets the change requirement of >100 or <-100:

```py
def updown(row, df):
    rownum = row.name
    up = (row['Price'] < df.loc[rownum:, 'Price'] - 100).argmax()
    down = (row['Price'] > df.loc[rownum:, 'Price'] + 100).argmax()
    return (
        df.loc[up + rownum, 'Time'] if up > 0 else pd.NaT,
        df.loc[down + rownum, 'Time'] if down > 0 else pd.NaT
    )

df[['Up_Time', 'Down_Time']] = df.apply(updown, axis=1, result_type='expand', df=df)
```

Output:

```
        Time    Price   Up_Time Down_Time
0   09:19:00  3252.25  14:02:00  11:39:00
1   09:24:00  3259.90  14:02:00  11:39:00
2   09:56:00  3199.40  14:02:00  12:18:00
3   10:17:00  3222.50  14:02:00  12:18:00
4   10:43:00  3191.25  14:02:00  12:18:00
5   11:39:00  3143.00  13:37:00  12:18:00
6   12:18:00  2991.70  13:20:00  14:52:00
7   13:20:00  3196.35  14:02:00  14:19:00
8   13:26:00  3176.10  14:02:00  14:19:00
9   13:34:00  3198.85  14:02:00  14:19:00
10  13:37:00  3260.75  14:02:00  14:19:00
11  14:00:00  3160.85  14:02:00  14:19:00
12  14:02:00  3450.00       NaT  14:19:00
13  14:19:00  3060.50       NaT  14:31:00
14  14:30:00  2968.70       NaT  14:57:00
15  14:31:00  2895.80       NaT  15:00:00
16  14:52:00  2880.70       NaT  15:00:00
17  14:53:00  2901.55       NaT  15:00:00
18  14:55:00  2885.55       NaT  15:00:00
19  14:57:00  2839.05       NaT  15:00:00
20  14:58:00  2871.50       NaT  15:00:00
21  15:00:00  2718.95       NaT       NaT
```

Comment: This definitely much faster. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @rakesh no worries - I'm glad I could help. But you might want to hold off accepting, you might still get an even better answer

Comment: @rakesh Probably too late now... keep it in mind for future questions though just to leave them unaccepted for maybe a day to try and get as many answers as possible. Once that first day is passed though its  unlikely you'll get any more though.